# How to apply order filter to hyperledger composer rest api

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, loopback

Not able to apply order filter to composer get request "/api/Commodity", Tried method recommended in LoopBack (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Order-filter.html)
filter={"order":"field_name ASC|DESC"}. but not working.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the Composer REST Server API states, that:

> Filters are similar to queries, but use the LoopBack filter syntax, and can only be sent using the Hyperledger Composer REST API. **Currently, only the WHERE LoopBack filter is supported.** The supported operators within WHERE are: =, and, or, gt, gte, lt, lte, neq. Filters are submitted using a GET call against an asset type, participant type, or transaction type; the filter is then supplied as a parameter. Filters return the results from the specified class, and will not return results from classes extending the specified class.

Please take a look at this: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/query.html#using-filters

Comment: yep saw some of the issues on github and they don't have any plans to support as well.